# Populating two ComboBoxColumns in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I have two `ComboBoxColumns` (`col_fon` being the first and `col_mon` the second one)in a `DataGridView`. However, only one `ComboBoxColumn` (`col_mon`) which is the second `ComboBoxColumn` existent in the `DataGridView` is showing data:

```
Private Sub Window_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    col_fon.ValueMember = "Code"
    col_fon.DisplayMember = "Name"
    col_fon.DataSource = LoadComboFon()
    col_fon.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic

    col_mon.ValueMember = "Code"
    col_mon.DisplayMember = "Name"
    col_mon.DataSource = LoadComboMon()
    col_mon.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic

End Sub
```

Each `ComboBoxColumn` present into the `DatagridView` has its proper `DataSource`, which is loaded by the following method (the `col_mon`, which is the `ComboBoxColumn` without problems) uses an identical method to the following):

```
Private Function LoadComboFon() As DataTable
    Dim dsParFon As New DataSet
    Dim dsFon As New DataSet
    Dim dtFon As New DataTable
    Dim Filter AS String
    Try
        Filter = "FONDO"
        dsParFon.Tables.Add("FONDOS")
        dsParFon.Tables("FONDOS").Columns.Add("FONDOS")
        dsParFon.Tables("FONDOS").Rows.Add(Filter)
        dsParFon.AcceptChanges()

        ' dsFon is loaded here with a method used by another classes

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
    dtFon = dsFon.Tables(0)
    dtFon.Columns("CodeFon").ColumnName = "Code"
    Return dtFon

End Function
```

I tried using `EditingControlShowing` and `SelectedIndexChanged` events but the first does nothing with the `DataGridView` and the other cannot be used with those columns (because they are into the `DataGridView` instead to be created and inserted into the `DataGridView`)

Is there another alternative to load the `DataSource` in the affected column without having problems with the another (and functional `ComboBoxColum`)? Thanks in advance

Comment: Um, the one thing you do NOT show us there is how the data is actually loaded, so how can we talk about "another" way to load the data?  That said, if you're using two completely separate `DataSets` then there's no way that the two columns can be "interfering" with each other on that basis.  I suggest that you debug your code properly and find out what is actually happening.  If all you're going on is that a column isn't showing data then you're assuming far too much.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense in that you create a `DataSet`, create a `DataTable` and then add a `DataTable` to your `DataSet` by name, thus creating another new `DataTable`.  Why would you have two `DataTables`?  Why would you have a `DataSet` at all?  Just create a `DataTable`, populate it and then bind it.  The `DataSet` is pointless.

Comment: The data is extracted from SQL, and I debugged the code. But it only shows a dataerror exception which has been controlled.

Comment: The data is obtained from SQL (because I am extracting the data from my DB), the problem is it does not display in my column for some reason. I debugged the code and it does not show why it isn't displaying the data. All the data is string and the stored procedures are only SELECT * FROM queries (those stored procedures are used by the column without problems). Which info do you need apart from the exposed in my post? I am searching for another alternative to display the data I need. The method for obtain the data is OK

Comment: And about why I used a `DataSet`, is because the method used for obtaining the data, it needs a `DataSet` for input and output. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem finally was in the `ComboBoxColumn` properties, which `ReadOnly` was setted in `ReadOnly = True`. I changed it to `False` and now it shows the desired data.